# Hello/hi removed in questions and answers

Tags: support

I've noticed that whenever I start a answer with either the word `hello` or `hi`, that word has been removed when I post the answer or attempt to update it. A few things I've noticed about this:

- Either word having any uppercase characters doesn't stop it from being removed
- If you change the spelling, like helo and hy, the words aren't removed
- They only get removed if you start the question or answer with it
- I've only observed/tested this on/with an answer, but I noticed that the question I was answering started with `Hy`, but the rest of the spelling (of the question) was fine, leading me to believe that this was done on purpose
- It also removes any punctuation that is directly after the word (for example: `Hello,`. The comma would be removed with the word hello or hi)

Comment: hi. (Simply could, of resist) are you asking for a more expansive / strict filter here? If you could edit this to show the results you wish to see, this can be considered as a bug request. If not, it’s more discussion and should be retagged.

Comment: @bmike no, I'm not asking for filter changes. This is a bug I've noticed. Should I re-tag it?

Comment: Yes. If you don’t propose a change, it’s not really a 

Comment: Ok, does that mean that it's part of the filter?

Answer (score 5):

This is by design, but I don’t know if this list is still current on the code.

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/165931
- [Why can't I greet you?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186173/why-cant-i-greet-you)

The sentiment that chit chat does not belong in any post is deeply embedded in the community since the value of a post is highest and most durable when the question is succinct and crystal clear.

Answers get a little more latitude, since the great ones have a clear succinct answer and then also elaboration as to context, or why the answer is correct.

Comment: Ok, shall I change this into a discussion about changing the filter?

Comment: It's highly unlikely to be changed, the consensus is that such greetings are noise: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/295232